# Python & API : Why do I get KeyErrors when run by python but the value is there in postman?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, postman

I am using the below code to return the raw json data from Harvest, by changing the URL called I have successfully created running scripts for 6 files, however I am having trouble with one and I can't work out why ...

```
import requests, json

AUTH = "Bearer  REDACTED"
ACCOUNT = "REDACTED"

URL = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/clients/?"
HEADERS = { "Authorization": AUTH,
            "Harvest-Account-ID": ACCOUNT,
            "Accept":"application/json"}

r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS).json()
total_pages = int(r['total_pages'])
total_entries = int(r['total_entries'])

results = []
for x in range(1, total_pages):
    response = requests.get(URL+"page="+str(x), headers=HEADERS)

    data = response.json()
    next_page = data["next_page"]
    results.extend(data["time_entries"])

filepath = "Z:/System Administrator/System Backups/08. Harvest/HARVEST_Clients.json"
with open(filepath, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results, outfile)

print('Done!')
print('Total Pages : '+str(total_pages))
print('Total Entries : '+str(total_entries))
```

When I run the above it gives me the desired result of
Done!
Total Pages : 3
Total Entries : 237

However if I try to use a URL with date variables I get KeyErrors. All I do is change the code from :

```
URL = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/clients/?"
```

to

```
URL = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=2017-04-01&to=2018-03-31/?"
```

And the results.extend variable from

```
results.extend(data["clients"])
```

to

```
results.extend(data["time_entries"])
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "Z:\System Administrator\System Backups\08. Harvest\Scripts\API_Harvest_Timesheets 2017-18.py", line 19, in 
>       total_pages = int(r['total_pages'])
>   KeyError: 'total_pages'

When I run the URL and authorisation through postman I get the following result

```
{
    "time_entries": [FULL DATA RESULT HERE]
    "per_page": 100,
    "total_pages": 138,
    "total_entries": 13711,
    "next_page": 2,
    "previous_page": null,
    "page": 1,
    "links": {
        "first": "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=2017-04-01&page=1&per_page=100&to=2018-03-31",
        "next": "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=2017-04-01&page=2&per_page=100&to=2018-03-31",
        "previous": null,
        "last": "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=2017-04-01&page=138&per_page=100&to=2018-03-31"
    }
}
```

So I can see that the 'total_pages' value is returned from that url and the value is 138 - so why doesn't this code run for this specific URL but runs fine for others ?

Comment: can you please post the contents of 'r' which is obtained as a result of calling the API with date?

Comment: If you do `r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS)`, then you can do `r.status_code`. Try printing the result of `r.json()`, maybe you're not getting what you expect.

Comment: your access token is experied, need to update it i guess

Comment: The results of r as defined in the query showed there was an error 
{'message': 'Invalid to date provided: "2018-03-31/?"'}
so I removed the /? from the end and reran. 
The r value now gives me the full data if I add the print before the total_pages / total_entries section and and now I get a key error on next_page

Comment: Again, check the result of `data = response.json()`

Comment: aha ! That did it : the error showed as {'message': 'Invalid to date provided: "2018-03-31page=1"'} so I changed the URL to "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=2017-04-01&to=2018-03-31&" and it appended the page=x variable onto it and ran as expected. Thank you for helping me figure out how best to troubleshoot

Comment: Awesome. I can highly recommend getting used to using a debugger for scenarios like this, as it allows you to go through your code, while observing the state of your variables - and without having to plaster your code with prints etc.